# ggplot2, how to skip NAs in geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a matrix that shows categorical values of the variables I used for some linear combinations and a corresponding r.squared value. Since the number of variables used for the linear combinations varies between 1 and 4, there are several NAs.

I use ggplot2 to get this output, which is pretty close to what I want:
[Rplot1.png](http://postimg.org/image/409ejpam3/)

However, I don't want the NAs to be displayed and I am unable to figure out how to do it `geom_text()` is displaying everything or giving me an error if I try something like `geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%1.0f",value[!is.na(value])))` because the length is wrong in this case.

Furthermore I would like to have the last column formated with a different precision (2 decimal places) and in a different color code.

My data:

```
col1 <- c(3, 12, 12,  4,  2,  4,  6,  4, 15, 13,  1,  4, 13, 13,  4,  4,  6, 13,  1,  4)
col2 <- c(14, 29, 33, NA,  3, 14, 14, NA, 18, 18,  3, NA, 18, 18,  5, NA, 14, 18,  3, NA)
col3 <- c(22, 33, NA, NA,  6, 23, NA, NA, 25, 25, NA, NA, 24, 25, NA, NA, 21, 25, NA, NA)
col4 <- c(25, NA, NA, NA,  9, NA, NA, NA, 31, NA, NA, NA, 25, NA, NA, NA, 27, NA, NA, NA)
col5 <- c(0.99879174731700204326, 0.99026853951234095064, 0.97577109510739901133, 0.94129388844778405510, 0.99280352772128999117, 0.96836063265002103595, 0.93791976583184200056,
      0.84138009684215697703, 0.98856063354420098399, 0.97136223282556599656, 0.79804189507803902082, 0.64147943288862196987, 0.99825754796980703532, 0.96893762747413503256,
      0.87923096638698294836, 0.78073080902317304464, 0.99370888114350197640, 0.95233511051330899111, 0.80470423703937299376, 0.62955867989309499677)

plotMat2 <- data.frame(cbind(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5),
                            row.names=c("data.max4","data.max3","data.max2","data.max1","data.3QT4","data.3QT3","data.3QT2","data.3QT1","data.median4","data.median3","data.median2",
                              "data.median1","data.mean4","data.mean3","data.mean2","data.mean1","data.1QT4","data.1QT3","data.1QT2","data.1QT1"))
names(plotMat2) <- c("SU" ,  "SU.1", "SU.2", "SU.3", "rsq" )
```

My code:

```
library(reshape)
cor_dat2 <- melt(as.matrix(plotMat2))
names(cor_dat2) <- c('Var1','Var2','value')
cor_dat2$Var1 <- factor(row.names(plotMat2), levels=rev(row.names(plotMat2)))
cor_dat2$Var2 <- factor(cor_dat2$Var2, levels=colnames(plotMat2))


library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data =  cor_dat2, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%1.0f",value))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
print(p)
```

Any help is appreciated,
thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: The melting of your data is a bit ambiguous. Can you rerun that part? When I melt I get two columns, but you're referring to 3.

Comment: forgot as.matrix() in cor_dat2 <- melt(as.matrix(plotMat2)). Should give 3 columns now.

Comment: Feel free t oedit your question to reflect this.

Comment: what are `dat$X2`?? `reshape` or `reshape2`?? Please copy your question and test it in a new R-session to be sure that it is reproducible.

Comment: I am sorry. I had  to clear my worksapce, there were several versions still in there. `dat$X2` is changed to `cor_dat2$Var2` now. I use `reshape`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just replace the `geom_text` with:

```
geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(is.na(value), "", sprintf("%1.0f",value)))) +
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I assume I can change precision and color for rsq with that `ifelse(value<1)` too. I will try.

Comment: probably with `if(is.na(value), "", ifelse(value < 1), bla, bla))`